# kohana throws me an error on the configuration file

Tags: kohana

I have a problem when you install Kohana.

I removed the install.php file, I then printed the error

> Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: kohana-3.3.3.1
>
> SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request.php [ 986 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you don't have any routes defined, that case [see the guide](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing)

Otherwise you may need to have a catch all route like the one below:

```
// catch all route
Route::set('catch-all', '<any>', array('any' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'my_controller',
        'action' => 'catchall',
    ));
```